# web page display problem

Tags: html, css

I have created web pages where am using pixel to position various html elements. 
It works fine on my current setting (1024 *768 ).But if I change the display setting to 
1600 * 1200 then the web page looks really small.

Is there a solution for this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only solution is to use a relative measurement system such as em or % rather than a fixed measurement system such as px.
A good place to start is this smashing magazine [writeup](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/06/02/fixed-vs-fluid-vs-elastic-layout-whats-the-right-one-for-you/)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the technique called "[fluid layout](http://css-tricks.com/the-perfect-fluid-width-layout/)".